# Linear function for condition1 and cubic function for condition2 in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data of participants that had numerous trials, where certain trials had one condition, and other trials were another.

My analyses show that for condition 1, there is a linear null effect (flat line), while for condition 2 there is a cubic effect. I want to plot them together.

The code below creates a plot that gives the cubic function for both groups:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=trial, y=y, group=condition, colour=condition)) +
  geom_point() + geom_jitter(height=0.2) + 
  geom_smooth(alpha=0.1, method="lm", formula = y ~ poly(x,3, raw=TRUE)) +
  labs(x="Trial", y="y") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1,9,18,27,36,45,54,63))
```

[image]

What I want is to not have the cubic function for condition 2, but have a linear function. I tried to force this through `aes()` calls within `geom_smooth()`, but this seems to give me a much flatter cubic function for condition 1:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=trial, y=y)) +
  geom_point(aes(group=condition, colour=condition)) + geom_jitter(height=0.2, aes(group=condition, colour=condition)) + 
  geom_smooth(alpha=0.1, method="lm", formula = y ~ poly(x,3, raw=TRUE), aes(group=(condition="1"), colour=(condition="1"))) + 
  geom_smooth(alpha=0.1, method="lm", aes(group=(condition="2"), colour=(condition="2"))) + 
  labs(x="Trial", y="y") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1,9,18,27,36,45,54,63))
```

[image]

Obviously this is not the way to go. How would I accomplish this? Script for reproducible example (first 250 lines of the total dataset, so your figures will be different) below:

```
structure(list(id = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L
), trial = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
61L), condition = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    y = c(NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", 
"trial", "condition", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 250L), class = "data.frame")
```

Edit: The reason I'm not using `geom_smooth()` using gam or loess, is because there are multiple polynomials in condition 1, so it will show more than just the cubic function if I use that solution. I wish to show the cubic function, not the composite of multiple polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter your data inside `geom_smooth`.

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=trial, y=y, colour=as.factor(condition))) +
 geom_point() + geom_jitter(height=0.2) + 
 geom_smooth(data = filter(dat, condition == 2), alpha=0.1, method="lm", formula = y ~ poly(x,3, raw=TRUE)) +
 geom_smooth(data = filter(dat, condition == 1), alpha=0.1, method="lm", formula = y ~ 1) +
 labs(x="Trial", y="y") +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,9,18,27,36,45,54,63))
```

Which gives you this plot

[image]